# Dynamic object in json

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2

I am working on a chat app and have a json response having dynamic objects in that, the dates in chat messages are dynamic. It changes. Please tell me how to make Model Class of this dynamic json. Please Help.

```
{
"result": 1,
"msg": "Data Found",
"data": {
    "user_detail": {
        "id": "3",
        "first_name": "Rashi",
        "last_name": "Singh",
        "image_url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlnagpsst/image/upload/h_200,w_200/v1658072836/nassibo/9479.jpg"
    },
    "chat_messages": {
        "2022-07-29": [
            {
                "id": "6",
                "chat_id": "4",
                "sender_id": "37",
                "reciever_id": "3",
                "message": "Hii",
                "date": "2022-07-29",
                "created_at": "2022-07-29 09:58:48",
                "user_id": "37"
            },
            {
                "id": "12",
                "chat_id": "4",
                "sender_id": "37",
                "reciever_id": "3",
                "message": "Kjhndkhjkdhjk",
                "date": "2022-07-29",
                "created_at": "2022-07-29 12:58:59",
                "user_id": "37"
            }
        ],
        "2022-07-30": [
            {
                "id": "13",
                "chat_id": "4",
                "sender_id": "37",
                "reciever_id": "3",
                "message": "Hii",
                "date": "2022-07-30",
                "created_at": "2022-07-30 12:21:45",
                "user_id": "37"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. In order to get this issue resolved, you'll need to show us what you've tried so far in the question. BTW: You should fix formatting of the JSON. BR

Comment: I solved using the map(key, string)

Answer (score 0):

```
                       val b = response.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("chat_messages")


                    for (key in b.keys()) {

                        Log.i("///// keys",key.toString())
                        Log.i("///// keys_b",b[key].toString())

                        val child = b.getJSONArray(key)

                        for ( i in 0 until child.length()){
                            val  subChild = JSONObject(child.getJSONObject(i).toString())
                            val id  = subChild.getString("id")
                            val chat_id  = subChild.getString("chat_id")
                            val sender_id  = subChild.getString("sender_id")
                            val message  = subChild.getString("message")
                            val user_id  = subChild.getString("user_id")

                            Log.i("///// child_sub $i :",id)
                            Log.i("///// child_sub $i :",chat_id)
                            Log.i("///// child_sub $i :",sender_id)
                            Log.i("///// child_sub $i :",message)
                            Log.i("///// child_sub $i :",user_id)


                        }
```